# failed to resolve android support library v7-appcompat

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I create empty project in android studio `2.3.3` and it by default has `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` in it's module level `build.gradle` file and it compiles ok, but when I specify any concrete version from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-2
gradle sync fails with message

[image]

I also tried the following notation `compile group: 'com.android.support', name:'v7-appcompat', version: '26.0.0'`, still no success.
I have

```
 jcenter()
    maven {
       url "https://maven.google.com"
   }
```

in repositories secion. ***Install repository and sync project*** button is not clickable. Support repository is updated:
[image]

Comment: did you try cleaning your build? Or try File > Invalidate and Cache.

Comment: @DroiDev tried, nothing happened

Comment: can you try 26.0.*?

Comment: are you connected to the internet? (probably if you're on here). Are you on a proxy that stops the connection? Just thinking outside the box.

Comment: @DroiDev ok, i'm not sure what I did, but somewhere in between several restarts and caches' cleans it started to work. looks like one of studio's glitches. probably should close the question now

Answer (score 1):

You misswrote the artefact name. Change it as below:

`compile 'com.android.support:v7-appcompat:26.0.0'`

to

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
```

or later.

Invalidate Cache, go to `File` > `Invalidates Caches`

[image]

Just click in the `Install Repository and sync Project` link to install the missing dependencies.

[image]

Then sync your project with the gradle files again.

---

Second solution, try uninstalling an reinstalling `Android Support Repository` again (I think its similar to clean cache):

[image]

Comment: It is not correct. Since v.26 the support libraries are in the google maven repo and not in the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error message:

> Failed to resolve com.android.support:**v7-appcompat**:26.0.0'

The right library is **appcompat-v7** and not **v7-appcompat**

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.x.x'
```